# The Inverse Fourier Transform $\mathcal{F}^{-1}(|\xi|^k)\in L^1$

Tags: fourier-analysis, lp-spaces, fourier-transform

I was trying this question asked earlier today:
[Inverse of a Fourier Transform is $L^1 \cap L^{\infty}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2880541/inverse-of-a-fourier-transform-is-l1-cap-l-infty?noredirect=1#comment5947361_2880541)

and I got the answer as long as I can show one thing:

$\mathcal{F}^{-1}(|\xi|^k)\in L^1(\mathbb{R^2})$, with   $k>0.$

i.e. the Inverse Fourier Transform of $|\xi|^k\in L^1(\mathbb{R}^2)$.

(note that here $\xi=(\xi_1,\xi_2)$ and $|\xi|^k=(\xi_1^2+\xi_2^2)^{k/2})$

Anyone know how to do it?

Comment: thanks to trying to answer my problem @mathBR!

Comment: you're welcome @PiresDankan !

Comment: It's definitely not true. If it was, we would get $|\xi|^k = \mathcal{F}\mathcal{F}^{-1}|\xi|^k \in L^\infty$.